# PowerShell format text file

Tags: powershell

I get the below output from a PowerShell query. I don't have access to the server to run the query, so I have no option to influence the output format.

Example:

```
Name          : folderC
FullName      : D:\folderA\folderB\folderC
Length        :
CreationTime  : 2/8/2014 11:12:58 AM
LastAccessTime: 2/8/2014 11:12:58 AM

Name          : filename.txt
FullName      : D:\folderA\folderB\filename.txt
Length        : 71560192
CreationTime  : 11/25/2015 3:10:43 PM
LastAccessTime: 11/25/2015 3:10:43 PM
```

How can I format above content to get something more usable, maybe like a table format like so:

```
Name|FullName|Length|CreationTime|LastAccessTime
```

Comment: Is the output objects or text? Pipe it through `Get-Member` (look for `TypeName` at the beginning of that output).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>As @alroc notes in a comment on the question, it is possible that *objects* are available to the OP, given that they state that the output is "from a Powershell query" - if so, simple reformatting of the object array using the usual cmdlets is an option.

By contrast, this answer assumes that only a *text* representation, as printed in the question, is available.</sup>

[Dave Sexton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34902595/45375) is a simpler and more elegant choice, if:

- the input has no *empty* values (the OP's sample input does).
- the input file is small enough to be read into memory as a whole.

Consider the approach below to **avoid the issues above** and/or **if you want more control over how the input is converted into custom objects**, notably with respect to creating properties with types other than `[string]`: extend the `toObj()` function below (as written, all properties are also just strings).

---

```
Get-Content File | % `
  -begin {
    function toObj([string[]] $lines) {
      $keysAndValues = $lines -split '(?<=^[^ :]+)\s*: '
      $htProps = @{}
      for ($i = 0; $i -lt $keysAndValues.Count; $i += 2) {
        $htProps.($keysAndValues[$i]) = $keysAndValues[$i+1]
      }
      return [PSCustomObject] $htProps
    }
    $lines = @()
  } `
  -process {
    if ($_.trim() -ne '') { 
      $lines += $_
    } else {
      if ($lines) { toObj $lines }
      $lines = @()
    }
  } `
  -end {
    if ($lines) { toObj $lines }
  } | Format-Table
```

**Explanation:**

- Uses `ForEach-Object` (`%`) with separate `begin`, `process`, and `end` blocks.
- The `-begin`, executed *once* at the beginning:

  - Defines helper function `toObj()` that converts a block of contiguous nonempty input lines to a single custom object.

    - `toObj()` splits an array of lines into an array of contiguous key-value elements, converts that array to a hashtable, which is then converted to a custom object.
  - Initializes array `$lines`, which will store the lines of a single block of contiguous nonempty input lines
- The `-process` block, executed *for each input line*:

  - If the input line at hand is nonempty: Adds it to the current block of contiguous nonempty input lines stored in array `$lines`.
  - Otherwise: Submits the current block to `toObj()` for conversion to a custom object, and then resets the `$lines` array to start the next block. In effect, `toObj()` is invoked for each *paragraph* (run of nonempty lines).
- The `-end` block, executed *once* at the end:

  - Submits the last paragraph to `toObj()` for conversion to a custom object.
- Finally, the resulting array of custom objects is passed to `Format-Table`.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to split the text into records, replace the colons with equals so that you can use the ConvertFrom-StringData to turn each record into a hash which you can then feed into New-Object to convert into an object. Outputting the the object into pipe separated data can then be done with the ConvertTo-Csv. Something like so:

```
$x = @"
Name           : folderC
FullName       : D:\folderA\folderB\folderC
Length         : 0
CreationTime   : 2/8/2014 11:12:58 AM
LastAccessTime : 2/8/2014 11:12:58 AM

Name           : filename.txt
FullName       : D:\folderA\folderB\filename.txt
Length         : 71560192
CreationTime   : 11/25/2015 3:10:43 PM
LastAccessTime : 11/25/2015 3:10:43 PM
"@

($x -split '[\r\n]+(?=Name)') | % {
  $_ -replace '\s+:\s+', '='
} | % {
  $_ | ConvertFrom-StringData
} | % {
  New-Object psobject -Property $_
}  | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter '|' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Kudos for the clever block-splitting approach and `ConvertFrom-StringData` / `New-Object` combo; the only problem is that `ConvertFrom-StringData` interprets unquoted `\ ` sequences as control-character escapes. Doubling the `\ ` instances in the input should fix that `($_ -replace '\s+:\s+', '=') -replace '\\', '\\'`

Comment: @mklement0 good point, probably needs a bit more testing with a larger data set. I think there maybe an issue when them is no value too. Maybe turning the strings into quoted strings might be the way to go. Make the replace: `$_ -replace '\s+:\s+', "'='"` and add another `$_ -replace '^|$', "'"`

Comment: Good point re empty values - they indeed cause problems. Quoting does _not_ help, unfortunately - `ConvertFrom-StringData` retains them as literals.